# "i" variable in "for" statement valid inside functions?

Tags: python, function, variables, for-loop

I am using this structure in python: call a function from a for loop; the function, inside, uses the i value of the iterator. Should I also pass the i value? or is it global? what is the best practice here?

```
def function_1(A):
   (use if "i" inside here)

for i in range (etc etc):
   function_1(A)
```

Comment: A function should work on its formal parameters alone and not use any implicit global state as much as possible…

Comment: If `function_1` needs the value, pass the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is really a function of `A`, you should definately pass the value of the iterator to it. The whole idea of a function is that it does some stand-alone operations using its parameters. The function should know nothing about the environment calling it. It should not know that it's called from a loop, nor what the variables are called in its caller. Otherwise, this function is useless anywhere outside this script, and will even be useless inside the same script if anything changes.

That's a general design principle, regarding functions, classes or modules/packages. An object should not know who is using it, the user should know how it is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 3):

If you need the value of `i` to be passed to `function_1` at each iteration of the loop, then your code would look something like:

```
def function_1(A):
    # use A...

for i in range(...):
  function_1(i)
```

In your definition of `function_1`, `A` is the name given inside the function to the argument you pass when it's called (in your case, `i`).

Comment: The variable `i` does exists in the global scope, since the for loop is in the global scope. Python for loops do not have their own scope.